# Dynamically adding `andWhere` to query in TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to dynamically add a where clause to a query in order to achieve filtering on an html table. I send an object to my API which indicates the filter key value pairs. It looks like the following:

```
{Location: 'Seattle', Status: 'Active'}
```

The way I'm adding each of these filters to the query is as follows:

```
const query = this.tableRepository.createQueryBuilder('myTable')
    .where('myTable.id = :id', {table_id})

var ind=1
for (let key in myObj){
    var varname = 'searchVal' + String(ind)
    const searchVal = myObj[key]
    query.andWhere(`row_value.row_data->> '${key}' ILIKE :${varname}`, {varname: `%{searchVal%`})
}
```

The error I keep getting is the following `ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] syntax error at or near ":" QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near ":"`. I'm positive that the error is being invoked by the last `{varname: '%{searchVal}%'}` but I don't know how to change it

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out - I was being stupid.

All I had to do was change the last `{varname: '%{searchVal}%'}` to `{[varname]: '%{searchVal}%'}`